# How to get two image matching percentage in Android using Open CV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I'm very new to android and Open CV,I have to compare two images and need to get the matching percentage with those given two images.
I tried with the below code,

```
Mat img1 = new Mat();
Mat img2 = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg1, img1);
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg2, img2);
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
DescriptorExtractor descriptor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);;
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

// First photo
Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
descriptor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);

// Second photo
Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();

detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
descriptor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

// Matching

MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
MatOfDMatch filteredMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);  

List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
Double max_dist = 0.0;
Double min_dist = 100.0;

for(int i = 0;i < matchesList.size(); i++){
    Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
    if (dist < min_dist)
        min_dist = dist;
    if ( dist > max_dist)
        max_dist = dist;
}

LinkedList<DMatch> good_matches = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
for(int i = 0;i < matchesList.size(); i++){
    Log.d("LOG!",(" :  matchesList.get(i).distance :" + matchesList.get(i).distance));
    Log.d("LOG!",(" :  1.5 * min_dist :" + min_dist));
    if (matchesList.get(i).distance  <= 1.5 * min_dist)
        good_matches.addLast(matchesList.get(i));
}
MatOfDMatch goodMatches = new MatOfDMatch();
goodMatches.fromList(good_matches);
List<DMatch> bestMatches=goodMatches.toList();

Collections.sort(bestMatches,new Comparator<DMatch>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(DMatch o1, DMatch o2) {
        if(o1.distance<o2.distance)
            return -1;
        if(o1.distance>o2.distance)
            return 1;
        else {
            Log.d("LOG!",("Equal i value: "));
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
Log.d("LOG!",("bestMatches.size() : "+bestMatches.size() + " :  goodMatches size :" + goodMatches.toList().size()));
```

I'm getting the matching points  and **best Matches** for these two given images. When I'm giving the exact images it is working perfectly fine (best match points more than 70). When I'm giving the slightly different images it's not giving the best match points (every time getting less than 10 best match points).

Comment: It will help immensely if you post some actual image pairs.